# Equivalent command for nlapiMergeTemplate in Netsuite 2015.2

Tags: netsuite

Anyone please tell the Equivalent command for 'nlapiMergeTemplate()' in 'Netsuite' 2015.2

Comment: I tried 'nlapiCreateEmailMerger()' command is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the NetSuite help center for `nlapiMergeTemplate` it is deprecated API and is only supported for CRMSDK templates:

> This API only supports CRMSDK templates. CRMSDK templates are deprecated as of Version 2015 Release 1. You can convert your existing CRMSDK templates to scriptable templates within the UI. See [Converting CRMSDK Templates to Scriptable Templates](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4038074365.html) for addition information. Scriptable templates are not supported with nlapiMergeRecord. Once your CRMSDK templates are converted, update all applicable scripts with nlapiCreateEmailMerger(templateId), nlobjEmailMerger, and nlobjMergeResult. Use [nlapiCreateEmailMerger(templateId)](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3027360.html#bridgehead_4183390688) as your starting point.

The correct way forward is first converting the CRMSDK templates to scriptable templates in the UI and then using `nlapiCreateEmailMerger`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go here https://github.com/BKnights/KotN-Netsuite for a library I wrote that's a drop-in replacement for nlapiMergeTemplate. It checks whether a template is an old or new style and makes the appropriate calls.